# Is it possible to have branches in a Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, p2p, bitcoin, multi-agent

I am using Blockchain to allocate tasks for agents in a multi-agent system. I wanted to know if it's possible to have branches in a Blockchain, If the answer is "yes", can a peers have different roles(miner or not miner) in each branch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible. The technology you mention `ethereum` and `bitcoin` are open-source project. You are free to change the rules and create branches, roles and whatever you like.

[Source code of Bitcoin on GitHub](https://www.google.com/search?q=github+bitcoin&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIL821IL821&oq=github+bitcoin&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2100j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[Source code of a popular implementation of Ethereum on GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation requirements it might be worth looking into Hyperledger Fabric. Fabric allows for peers with different roles as well as multiple concurrent ledgers across different peers. See https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/peers/peers.html for more details